# Best practice for custom product fields in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I was wondering if somebody has any experience with custom product fields in WooCommerce. I'm currently working on an online-shop for food and beverages, which contains a lot of custom values and different product types like food, beverages or non-food.

So far I was working with ACF, which already helped me to save a lot of time in dev. But still I'm not very sure if this is the best practice. I very concerned about being limited in what I'm doing (Online-Shop will contain apprx. 4000 products).

I found this very nice article about adding custom fields to WooCommerce products (http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/). The first benefit is that the admin's don't need to get used to two different UI's while editing product.

Would be great if somebody could share his experience with custom fields in WooCommerce.

**List of fields I manly use:**

- Checkboxes (sometimes Conditional)
- Regular Text-Inputs Textarea's Select to link to other custom post types
- Radiobuttons
- Select > For `product_cat`
- Mandotory fields

Comment: Custom fields with custom code are the cleanest way and you can do whatever you want in Woocommerce without any limitations, but it's a bit longer when you are not use to them, and you need to find the right hooks to embed them in the desired locations. Plugins are quicker, and require few coding, but they have always limitations… In stackOverFlow, tutorial or plugin recommendations are of-topic, as we only (mainly) manage custom coding issues related questions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! :) I think I'll go the code way.. Don't want any limitations.. Cheers